# How to check if request.GET or request.POST is from a particular part of a URL?

Tags: python, django, post, get

**Technologies:** Django 1.7.7, Python 3

```
currentUrl = request.get_full_path()
if request.method == 'POST' and request.POST('/path/to/thing', currentUrl):
    # Do something
```

I'm trying to check if the request method is a POST and if the request is coming from a particular URL, but not including the users input as as part of the url (if that makes sense).

So, for example, let's say a user is filling out a form and he/she submits the word "hello." I want to check to see if the form is from "some/base/url" without checking to see if the word "hello" is in the url too.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Found this to work:

```
  if request.method == 'GET' and '/path/to/thing' in request.path_info
```

Comment: What about this as a possible solution? It works for me anyway: if request.method == 'GET' and '/path/to/thing' in request.path_info:

Answer (score 1):

> #### HttpRequest.POST
>
> A dictionary-like object containing all given HTTP POST parameters,
> providing that the request contains form data

`HttpRequest.POST` is not a method to use.

In case you have multiple options to do with your form for example you want to have a submit button, and a submit button with add another then you will need to give a name for each button, and then check wither the name in the POST parameters or not.

In case you are afraid of having the form submitted from unknown place. then `csrf_token` do it for you.

> The CSRF middleware and template tag provides easy-to-use protection
> against Cross Site Request Forgeries. This type of attack occurs when
> a malicious Web site contains a link, a form button or some javascript
> that is intended to perform some action on your Web site, using the
> credentials of a logged-in user who visits the malicious site in their
> browser. A related type of attack, ‘login CSRF’, where an attacking
> site tricks a user’s browser into logging into a site with someone
> else’s credentials, is also covered.

Read:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/request-response/
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/csrf/